# Two Different Dependent Drop Down Lists on Excel with Same Name Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, data-validation

I'm hoping to achieve the following (using lists from data validation).

A1 cell dropdown menu: Paint, Replace, or Repair
 - A2 cell dropdown menu: Replace, Repair
 - A3 cell dropdown menu: Paint, Repair

I want both A2 and A3 to be dependent on A1, given that if A1="Replace" then the dropdown menu for A2 is strictly "Replace", and the dropdown menu for A3 is strictly "Paint". However, if A1 is selected as the paint or repair options, the dropdown lists for A2 & A3 remain unchanged.

The problem I'm running into on excel with this is that I can't have two separate dependent lists (on the cell A1) with the same name range of "Paint, Replace, Repair".

Someone please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will solve the issue:**

*Situation 1 (DD 1 has **Replace**):*

[image]

*Situation 2 (DD 1 has **Paint/Repare**):*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `B126`:

  `=IF(E121="Replace","Replace",IF(OR(E121="Repare",E121="Paint"),"Replace",))`
- Formula in Cell `C126`:

  `=IF(E121="Replace","Paint",IF(OR(E121="Repare",E121="Paint"),"Paint",))`
- Reach to Cell `E121` and apply **Data Validation** as shown in screen shot below.

[image]

- For Drop Down 2:

[image]

- For Drop Down 3:

[image]

## Edited:

- To get  **Replace** & **Repair** in drop down 2, if **Paint** or **Repare** is selected in Drop Down 1.
- Enter this Formula in cell `B127`.

  `=IF(OR(E121="Repare",E121="Paint"),"Repare","")`
- Go to **Data Validation** and edit **Source** Range.
- For Drop Down 2:

[image]

**Note,** repeat steps shown in Edited part for Drop Down 3 (*including the Formula in `C127`*).

**Caveat:**

- This method is purely all around OP's need, don't consider it as General solution.

*You may adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: This was helpful thanks! I guess I should have clarified a bit more though.. What you posted helps well with fixing the other drop down menus based off if "Replace" is chosen in Drop Down 1. But what I need is that if "Paint" or "Repair" is chosen in Drop Down 1, I need Drop Down 2 to have the original selections of "Replace" & "Repair", and Drop Down 3 with original selections of "Paint" & "Repair".

Comment: @kknor,,, glad to help you,, now you may accept it as Answer and Up vote also!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Three drop downs with drop down 2 and 3 having there values taken from 1.

Alternatively you could formulate the drop down like so, within the "data validation → list → source":

> In drop down 1, have `=$A$6,$A$5:$A$7`, in drop down 2 have `=IF($A$1="Replace",$A$6,$A$5:$A$7)` and in drop down 3 `=IF($A$1="Replace",$A$5,$A$5:$A$7)`

So basically it only shows the necessary values at the right times